# Proof of fourier transformation of multiplication of two signals

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, frequency-domain

I've been trying to find a proof of the following, but still I m unable to proof it, can someone help me?
$$
ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} 
 [X(\omega)*G(\omega)]
$$
[image]

Comment: You can’t have looked very hard for the proof. Almost any text on signal processing will do.

Comment: @DilipSarwate O dear, Can you suggest me text that has proof of this?

Comment: Try replacing **only** $x(t)$ by its representation as the inverse Fourier transform of $X(\omega)$ so that the integral formula for $X_q(\omega)$ involves only two integrals instead of the three that you have.  _Then_ interchange the order of integration.  When you finish solving the question, write up a nicely LaTexed answer and post it. Yes, it is permissible (even encouraged) to post an answer to one's own question.

Answer (score 5):

I am very thankful to *[Dilip-sarwate](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/235/dilip-sarwate)* and *[Gilles](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/1629/gilles)*, who took their precious time to understand my problem and guide me.
So, Now I'm going to write the correct solution to my question. Which is as follows:
 $$
ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}[x(t)g(t)]e^{-j\omega t}dt
$$
As we know : 
$$
x(t) = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\alpha)e^{j\alpha t}d\alpha 
$$
Therefore,
$$
ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\alpha)e^{j\alpha t}d\alpha\bigg]g(t) e^{-j\omega t}dt
$$
After rearranging, we have
$$
ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\alpha)\bigg[\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j(\omega-\alpha)t}dt\bigg]d\alpha
$$
As we also know that :
$$
G(\omega) = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt
$$
and replacing $\omega$ with $\omega-\alpha$, we get:
$$
G(\omega-\alpha) = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-j(\omega-\alpha)t}dt
$$
Therefore,
$$ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\alpha)G(\omega-\alpha)d\alpha$$
Finally, we get
**$$
ℱ[x(t)g(t)] = \frac 1{2\pi}[X(\omega)*G(\omega)]
$$**

[$\because$ $x_1(t)*x_2(t) = \int_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}x_1(\tau)x_2(t-\tau)d\tau$]

Comment: Good job. After a couple of days, you can even accept your own answer as the most satisfactory answer.

Comment: You're welcome, well done!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Write it as:
$$
\mathcal{F}\big\{x_1(t)x_2(t)\big\} = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{X_1(\alpha)\big\}x_2(t)\bigg]e^{-j\Omega t}dt
$$

You correctly used the inverse Fourier transform of $X_1(\alpha)$ for a new expression of $x_1(t)$ as in $(1)$

$$
x_1(t) = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X_1(\alpha)e^{j\alpha t}d\alpha\tag{1} 
$$
Don't express $x_2(t)$ in the form of the inverse Fourier transform, leave it as it is and you'll end up with an exponential to the power $-j(\Omega - \alpha)t$. The expression can be further simplified and give equation $(2)$
$$
\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X_1(\alpha)X_2(\Omega - \alpha)d\alpha\tag{2}
$$